# Non working render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, render

I get the errors message in the title and I can't understand why?

this my code
user.rb

```
has_one :GoldBook
has_many :comments
```

gold_book.rb

```
has_many :comments
belongs_to :user
```

comment.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :gold_book
```

comments_controller.rb

```
def create
@gold_book = GoldBook.find(params[:gold_book_id])
@comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
@comment.goldbook = @gold_book
@comment.user = current_user
```

gold_books/show.html.erb

```
<%= render 'goldbook' %>
```

gold_books/_goldbooks

```
<%= render 'comments/form', goldbook: goldbook %>
```

comments/_form

```
    <%= form_for([goldbook, @comment]) do |f| %>
    <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I think the error is in the comments' form but not sure ...
I'm trying to make somethink like a gold book with many comment

And this is the full trace error :

```
activemodel (3.2.8) lib/active_model/naming.rb:163:in `model_name_from_record_or_class'
activemodel (3.2.8) lib/active_model/naming.rb:158:in `param_key'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:369:in `form_for'
app/views/comments/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_comments__form_html_erb__1022796803_80617610'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:265:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:238:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:237:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
app/views/gold_books/_goldbook.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_gold_books__goldbook_html_erb__357761412_79186410'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:265:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:238:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:237:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
app/views/gold_books/show.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_gold_books_show_html_erb__197041322_85056980'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:196:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/gold_books_controller.rb:18:in `show'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__799128830__process_action__547441087__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:339:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1022103052__call__645886376__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: When I'm requesting gold_books/17 (where 17 is an id) I get :  NoMethodError in Gold_books#show
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Comment: Please add the full error message, including the backtrace, in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: please show the code from router, the action which is responsible for `gold_books/17`.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for I'm sorry ... What do you mean by "the code from router, the action which is responsible for gold_books/17"

Answer (score 1):

Associations are case-sensitive. Change this:

```
has_one :GoldBook
```

to

```
has_one :gold_book
```

Also, your instance variable is called `@gold_book`, but in your `show` view you're referring to `goldbook`. Try changing it to:

```
<%= render 'comments/form', gold_book: @gold_book %>
```

In general, make sure you adhere to the naming conventions of Rails. Take a look at [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action), particularly the section on "Rendering by default".

Comment: If i do that the other parts doesn't work anymore and they was working before :/

Comment: That's unfortunate, but your association is still incorrectly defined as it is.